# Right to left direction for multiple inline span

Tags: html, css, inline, right-to-left

I have two inline spans with some English letters inside. However I need the direction to be right-to-left (RTL), but the webpage doesn't show spans properly.

First span: `<span>4 Series Gran Coupe</span>`

Second span: `<span>(1)</span>`

They supposed to be like this:

`(1) 4 Series Gran Coupe`

What I see on the webpage is this:

[image]

I don't want to use `float:right` as it affects other elements next to those spans.

Comment: enter some problem  code here

Comment: I think you don't have to do anything. If you put the second span first and the other in second then it shows the behavior by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put theme in a parent `div` and set `display: inline-block` for `span`s:

```css
.parent{
  direction: rtl;
}
.parent span{
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>4 Series Gran Coupe</span>
    <span class="left">(1)</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Although it works... text direction is not text alignment

Answer (score 1):

## Text alignment is not text direction

I can see clearly that you are mixing between text alignment and text direction. Even though they might sound the same but they are not. Text alignment is where do you want to **place or display the text** (left/center/right). Text direction is about the **order of the characters** (the writing system). You can have RTL text aligned to the left, and vice versa. Check the live example below to see the difference between text direction vs alignment.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="rtl-lang">بين (قوسين)</p>
<p class="ltr-lang">between (brackets)</p>

<button onclick="$('.rtl-lang').css('direction', 'rtl')">Arabic rtl</button>
<button onclick="$('.rtl-lang').css('direction', 'ltr')">Arabic ltr</button>
<button onclick="$('.rtl-lang').css('text-align', 'right')">Arabic align right</button>
<button onclick="$('.rtl-lang').css('text-align', 'left')">Arabic alight left</button>
<br />
<button onclick="$('.ltr-lang').css('direction', 'rtl')">English rtl</button>
<button onclick="$('.ltr-lang').css('direction', 'ltr')">English ltr</button>
<button onclick="$('.ltr-lang').css('text-align', 'right')">English align right</button>
<button onclick="$('.ltr-lang').css('text-align', 'left')">English align left</button>
```

As a rule never use RTL direction for LTR language (e.g. English, French, German...). Only use RTL direction if you have a text in one of the RTL languages (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew, Farsi...).

Now let's go back to your question. Basically, you need to use `text-align: right` in the parent `<div>` then inverse the order of your `<span>`s

```css
.parent {
  text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>(1)</span>
    <span>4 Series Gran Coupe</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the body is RTL, you have to use LTR for the spans and aligning them to the right:

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
  margin: 56px 30px 0px;
  /*margins are only for the snippet proper display */
}
.ltr_div {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="ltr_div">
  <span>(1)</span>
  <span>4 Series Gran Coupe</span>
</div>
```